# using titletoc to add vertical spacing in table of contents which wraps to multiple pages

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I'm setting up some course materials which will be in the article document class and have several parts. At the beginning of each part, I want to add in a page with the section names and some white space after each for the students to write in a brief summary. I'd like to set up a command to do this automatically because I or others may be editing these in future to add in extra parts, and I would like it if the document will reformat the notes page automatically.

I've tried to do it using titletoc, but I'm running into issues. This is the best I've figured out, but it requires me to force a standard set of white space in between each item. If I set the space the wrong size and there are enough sections to wrap to the next page, then it may put one section at the very bottom and not leave the white space. To make it even worse, for reasons I cannot figure out, sometimes a value of \addvspace that works in one section will be too short in another. Ideally, I'd tell latex to put 3 on a single page and use \vspace{\stretch{1}}, but I have no idea how to tell it to count.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{titletoc,titlesec}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\titlecontents{section}[0pt]{\addvspace{0pt}}{\bfseries\makebox[10pt][l]{\thecontentslabel\enspace}}{\contentsmargin{0pt}}{}[\addvspace{10pc}]

\newcommand\makenotespage{
\startcontents[mainsections] 
\printcontents[mainsections]{l}{1}{\section*{Daily summary}\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} \newpage}

\begin{document}
\part{Demo}

\makenotespage

\section{First}
Some stuff
\newpage

\section{Next}
Some stuff
\newpage

\section{Again}
Some stuff
\newpage

\section{Some more}
Some stuff
\newpage

\section{Finally}
Some stuff

\end{document}
```

On a side note, I'm having issues with the header, too - I had intended to use no page numbers or headers on the notes pages; this is optional, but it would be nice if I could get rid of them. I tried adding this to \makenotespage:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{page}{0}
```

It worked fine with onesided, but on twosided it only works for the first page.

Thanks in advance for all suggestions! I can switch to another document class or another package, but it would be really helpful if it's compatible with titlesec.